# Testing CSRF vulnerability

Tags: php, html, csrf

In my php page `(register.php)` there's a form and I want to check if it's vulnerable to CSRF (as I expect to be):

```
<form method="post" name="registration">
    <label>Nome</label><br>
    <input name="nome" type="text" autofocus required="required" placeholder="Nome">
    <input name="cognome" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Cognome"><br>
    <label>Azienda</label><br>
    <input name="azienda" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Azienda"><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Registrami">
</form>
```

To test the vulnerability I visited from the browser the url

```
http://localhost/myfolder/register.php?nome=MyName&cognome=MySurname&azienda=University
```

I expected the browser to fill the fields of the form, but that doesn't happen.

Could you clarify why?

Comment: Why are you sending parameters as a `GET` request?

Comment: I'm testing it at the same way as he does in this tutorial http://youtu.be/3yrpRfdtYc4?t=1m33s

Comment: Any form, whose parameters are predictable, is vulnerable to CSRF.

Comment: It's a 15 minute video. Could you please edit the question and add the relevant info there? I mean, I haven't seen it and I can't understand why a browser would take GET parameters in the URL and use their values to populate a random POST form within the page.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario — The *browser* wouldn't. The video shows the value of the `value` attributes being echoed using data from some abstraction of `$_REQUEST`)

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers only fill form fields with autocomplete data.

For data to get from the URL to the form, the server has to parse the data in the URL and use it to populate the from fields.

e.g.

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['nome']); ?>"
```

The fact that your code does not do that does not mean the form is not vulnerable to CSRF though.

CSRF attacks replace the form entirely (often with an invisible form, pre-populated with malicious data and submitted with JavaScript and hosted on a different website (hence "Cross-Site"). The goal of a CSRF attack isn't to put data into the *form*, but into whatever the form *submits to*.

There is rarely any point in attacking a registration form. A more likely target would be a comment form (so an already registered and signed in user on Site A would be used to submit comments written by the owner of Site B). Site B's spam would then be created using the users account on Site A.